# Input types in Typescript interface

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I'm trying to write a component to reuse and one of the varibles is the input type to render.

Currently, I have this:

```
type InputBaseProps = {
  children?: ReactChild;
  className?: string;
  id: string;
  label?: string;
  name?: string;
  onBlur: (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  onChange: (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  placeholder?: string;
  style?: CSSProperties;
  type: ????;
  value?: string;
};
```

I want to allow only valid HTML `types`, like the entire list defined here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes it is simple, you just put | between all the types you want. For example it would be like so

"button" | "checkbox" | "color" | "date" | "datetime-local" | "email" | "file" | "hidden" | "image" | "month" | "number" | "password" | "radio" | "range" | "reset" | "search" | "submit" | "tel" | "text" | "time" | "url" | "week"

These were all grabbed from the w3schools page you listed

Please accept this if this fits your needs

Comment: Thanks! It worked as I expected. 

I've found this solution by my own,  just feels a bit verbose. I think there is a simpler way to do it.

Comment: What is your own solution? I'm curious to know

Comment: Just used a solution like yours. I think it should be a better solution, instead of writing each single option by hand or copy pasting.

Comment: I just wrote a quick javascript program to do it, probably took way longer to write than copy paste but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @herohamp Does intellisense work with your method?

Answer (score 46):

```
import { HTMLInputTypeAttribute } from "react";

type InputBaseProps = {
    type?: HTMLInputTypeAttribute 
}
```

`HTMLInputTypeAttribute` resolves to the ff:

```
type HTMLInputTypeAttribute = "number" | "search" | "button" | "time" | "image" | "text" | "checkbox" | "color" | "date" | "datetime-local" | "email" | "file" | "hidden" | "month" | "password" | "radio" | "range" | ... 5 more ... | (string & {})
```

Intellisense working fine.

Answer (score 9):

This is how you should be doing this:

```
interface Props extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  //...add your custom types here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In React, you can use the `HTMLInputTypeAttribute` from `react`.

Answer (score 0):

**Create an exportable enum ...**

```
export enum InputType {
    button = "button",
    checkbox = "checkbox",
    color = "color",
    date = "date",
    datetimelocal = "datetime-local",
    email = "email",
    file = "file",
    hidden = "hidden",
    image = "image",
    month = "month",
    number = "number",
    password = "password",
    radio = "radio",
    range = "range",
   reset = "reset",
    search = "search",
    submit = "submit",
    tel = "tel",
    text = "text",
    time = "time",
    url = "url",
    week = "week"
};
```

**Then you can do ...**

```
type InputBaseProps = {
  children?: ReactChild;
  className?: string;
  id: string;
  label?: string;
  name?: string;
  onBlur: (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  onChange: (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  placeholder?: string;
  style?: CSSProperties;
  type: String as () => InputType;
  value?: string;
};
```

**Then using it ...**

```
import {InputType} from './file-your-enum-is-in';
const el: InputBaseProps  = {
    ...
    type: InputType.text,
    ...
};
```